# Can we send an email with excel containing multiple worksheets in oracle?

Tags: oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper

I wish to send an email which will contain one excel file with multiple sheets in oracle SQL developer.

Comment: Does this help? [How Can I Send Emails in PL/SQL (Oracle)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54968189/how-can-i-send-emails-in-pl-sql-oracle)

Comment: Thanks Abra but thus is not the solution am looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refer to below link for above question:
Steps which i performed are listed below:

Step 1: compile above procedure [This link will allow to send an email attaching file from FTP which will be created in step 2]

https://renaps.com/en/blog/how-to/simple-example-of-sending-attachments-using-utlsmtp

Step 2: This procedure will let you create an excel with multiple sheets and which will be generated in FTP i.e directory

https://community.oracle.com/thread/2544010?start=0&tstart=0

Step 3: Execute below command to receive mail.

set serveroutput on

exec mail_files('<from_email_id>', '<to_email_id>', '<subject_line>', 'message_body', '<directory_name>', '<file_name_to_be_attached>');